# Why can't I get sound through HDMI with nVidia GTX580

Tags: 10.04, sound, nvidia, hdmi, alsa

I've just installed the newest version of ALSA and my NVIDIA device showed up in the `gnome-volume-control`. I can't actually get any sound on the TV though. When searching around it seems the solution for 95% of people is to "unmute the device". My device is not muted or disabled:

[image: Sound Preferences - Hardware]

[image: Sound Preferences - Output]

My TV is not muted and it gets sound perfectly from my Xbox. Also, switching to "Internal Audio Analog Stereo" or "Logitech G930 Headset Analog Stereo" works and gives me sound. Additionally when booting to Windows the HDMI audio works fine. I don't know what to make of the AlsaMixer though:

[image: AlsaMixer - HDA NVidia]

Why can't I get any sound on my TV through NVidia GTX580? Here's my alsainfo output: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e41666ca9765badc84098ee4bc18c2c38f4bd856

Comment: Have you tried unmuting the other S/PDIF channels in alsamixer?

Comment: @Oli I don't know how

Comment: Press left and right to change selected channel, m to toggle mute.

Comment: @Oli: Unfortunately un-muting didn't have any effect. They are now all at 0 and I can't turn them up

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to "mute"/disable your other sound drivers, leaving only the HDMI output left? Ubuntu has had problems in the past when it came to detecting specific audio drivers to use (And by that I mean the ones you want active)

Comment: Disabled all other audio devices so that HDMI was the only remaining option in the Output tab - didn't make any difference

Comment: @Codemonkey, ok, have you tried disabling pulse audio using the command "sudo killall pulseaudio"?